# Implementing backend yii

Tags: php, yii, admin

I am trying to implement the directory structure from the yii wiki
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/33/

I have everything setup properly I believe but when I try to use the urlManger within the backend/config/main i recieve this error.

Property "CWebApplication.urlManager" is read only

//backend/config/main.php

```
<?php
$backend=dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$frontend=dirname($backend);
Yii::setPathOfAlias('backend', $backend);

return array(
    'basePath' => $frontend,

    'controllerPath' => $backend.'/controllers',
    'viewPath' => $backend.'/views',
    'runtimePath' => $backend.'/runtime',

    'import' => array(
        'backend.models.*',
        'backend.components.*',
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
    ),
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        //'caseSensitive'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
     //       'admin'=>array('adminUser', 'caseSensitive'=>false),
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think urlManager is a component. Try putting it in the components config array:

```
return array(
    'basePath' => $frontend,

    'controllerPath' => $backend . '/controllers',
    'viewPath' => $backend . '/views',
    'runtimePath' => $backend . '/runtime',

    'import' => array(
        'backend.models.*',
        'backend.components.*',
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
    ),

    'components' => array(
        'urlManager' => array(
            'urlFormat' => 'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            //'caseSensitive'=>false,
            'rules' => array(
                // 'admin'=>array('adminUser', 'caseSensitive'=>false),
            )
        ),
    ),
);
```